# Angular drag and drop cdk is not scrolling container when dragging

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7, angular-cdk

I am developping a frontend app in which i am using angular 7.I am using angular cdk for dragging and dropping elements but the problem is when i make a drag the div container is not scrolling.So is there any sollution for that.

https://angular-2cdcbb.stackblitz.io

[image]

this is my html

```
<div class="col_container" >
  <div class="column" cdkDrag>
    box
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my css

```
.col_container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1px;
  border-color: black;
}
.column {

  color: blue;
  background-color: azure;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0.1px;
  border-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  margin: 0 6px;
  vertical-align:top;

}
```

this is my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'scrollTestForDragAndDrop';
}
```

the expected behaviour is when i drag the box to the border the yellow div must scroll

Comment: Can you make simple demo app on "https://stackblitz.com/" site, and share it?

Comment: https://angular-2cdcbb.stackblitz.io